# Delete image with Ajax from database mysql (using Spring MVC+Hibernate)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to delete an image from my gallery without refresh the page. The solution is use Ajax but i don't known how because i am newbie with ajax. This is the code used for delete image from my database and this is implemented in my DAOImpl:

```
@Override
public void eliminaImage(int id_foto) {
    Image imageDaEliminare;
    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Image.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id_foto", id_foto));
    imageDaEliminare = (Image) crit.uniqueResult();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.delete(imageDaEliminare);
    session.flush();
}
```

This my controller that are used for show gallery and delete image from it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/homeUtente", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndex(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("galleria", usersService.getAllFoto());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/homeUtente", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView eliminaImage(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("id_foto") int id_foto) {
        usersService.eliminaImage(id_foto);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("galleria", usersService.getAllFoto());
        return mav;
    }
```

And this is my view page:

```
<c:forEach var="gallery" items="${galleria}">
    <div class="uk-overlay">
        <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,${gallery.value}" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
            <img id="my_image2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${gallery.value}" width="400" height="250" alt=""></img>
        </a>
        <div class="elimina">
            <form action="homeUtente" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_foto" value="${gallery.key}">
                <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-trash-o" id="submit"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Finally i tried to write this ajax code for delete image but i don't know how hide the deleted image:

```
$('.elimina').each(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:"homeUtente",
    type:'post',
    data:{id:'this.id_foto'},
    success:function(result){
        //TO IMPLEMENT!
    }
    error:function(err){
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image that you want to delete in a "global" var and in the success event remove it.

```
var imageToDelete;

$('.elimina').each(function(){

imageToDelte = $(this)
$.ajax({
    url:"homeUtente",
    type:'post',
    data:{id:'this.id_foto'},
    success:function(result){

        // to remove the element
        $(imageToDelete).closest('.uk-overlay').remove();
        // OR if you only want to hide it
        $(imageToDelete).closest('.uk-overlay').hide();

    }
    error:function(err){
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Show a popup for confirm the delete of image adding this key before of "success":

```
beforeSend:function(){
      //do anything
}
```